# syncookies and tcp options

Tags: linux, tcp-ip

enabling syncookies is  helping against some attacks
but the official docs still say [syncookies seriously violate TCP protocol, do not allow
    to use TCP extensions](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt)

Today I discover that once upon a time in the kernel development syncookies were extended to handle also [Timestamp, ECN, SACK, WScale](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/ipv4/syncookies.c)

So

1. how can I find from which kernel version ?
2. enabling syncookies and also Timestamp, ECN, SACK, WScale : how do other operating systems behave ?

Comment: as 'other operating systems' I mean also older linuxes